# find some strings and replace another string using notepad++ regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, notepad++

In several `Php Web Pages`, I'd like to add some extra `html code` to an existing (and pre-existent) `html code`. For example I have:

```
<a class="fix" name="P169336">&nbsp;</a>
```

I'd like to use this example to replace another `html code` which is located in other place of the same `Web Page`. For example I have:

```
class="hyperlink">Alessandro Marinuzzi</a></td></tr>
```

So using the first (example) add to the second (example) as below:

```
class="hyperlink">Alessandro Marinuzzi</a><br /><br /><div class="srtgs" id="rt_169336"></div></td></tr>
```

Where `rt_169336` is get from:

```
<a class="fix" name="P169336">&nbsp;</a>
```

Every `Web Page` has a own:

```
<a class="fix" name="PXXXXXX">&nbsp;</a>
```

You can find...

```
<a class="fix" name="P169336">&nbsp;</a>
```

or

```
<a class="fix" name="P167223">&nbsp;</a>
```

or another other number that changes for every `Web Page`...

I'd like to do this replacement using the ability of `notepad++` `regular expressions`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for

```
(<A CLASS="fix" NAME="P)(\d+)(">&nbsp;</A>)(.*?)(Marinuzzi</A>)(</TD></TR>)
```

where

- `(<A CLASS="fix" NAME="P)` Group 1, data before the number
- `(\d+)` Group 2, the number
- `(">&nbsp;</A>)` Group 3, data after the number
- `(.*?)` Group 4, data between search and replace sections
- `(Marinuzzi</A>)` Group 5, data before replace
- `(</TD></TR>)` Group 6, data after replace

And replace with

```
\1\2\3\4\5<BR><BR><DIV CLASS="srtgs" ID="rt_\2"></DIV>\6
```

where

- `\1\2\3\4\5` Reinsert groups 1-5
- `<BR><BR><DIV CLASS="srtgs" ID="rt_\2"></DIV>` insert new content with group 2
- `\6` Reinsert group 6

Search mode must be `Regular expression` with `. matches newline` enabled.

Note that this code assumes that search element is BEFORE the target element.